# Check consecutive numbers recursively using Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp

I'm trying to write a recursive function to check if the elements of a list are increasing consecutively.

```
(defun test (lst)   
 (if (null lst)
   1
   (if (= (car lst) (1- (test (cdr lst))))
    1     
    0)))

(setq consecutive '(1 2 3 4))
(setq non-consecutive '(2 5 3 6))
```

The results are:

```
CL-USER> (test non-consecutive)
0
CL-USER> (test consecutive)
0
```

`(test consecutive)` should return 1. How can I write this function correctly?

Comment: your recursion tests (car lst) vs. (1- "return of test call"), that is always (1- 0) or (1- 1)

Comment: How to arrange that part correctly in a recursive manner?

Comment: What should `(test '(1 3 5 7))` return?

Comment: @sds consecutive odd numbers need not be checked at all. Aynway, if I can check the '(1 2 3 4) sequence, I can check for it too I guess. By the way is the '(1 2 3 4) sequence called also the "successive numbers" in English? What is the most correct name for such a sequence, i.e. wehre the numbers increase one by one?

Comment: @Romario: Are you testing consecutive or increasing?

Comment: @sds Basically testing only the one-by-one increasing numbers is enough for me. By the way, is there an english word to  donate exclusively that kind of numbers i.e. only the 1 2 3 4 ... and not 1 3 5 or 2 4 6 or 123123123 or Fibonacci sequence, if you see what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that the numbers in the sequence are *consecutive*, i.e.,
increasing with step 1, you need this:

```
(defun list-consecutive-p (list)
  (or (null (cdr list))
      (and (= 1 (- (second list) (first list)))
           (list-consecutive-p (rest list)))))
```

Then

```
(list-consecutive-p '(1 2 3 4))
==> T
(list-consecutive-p '(1 4))
==> NIL
(list-consecutive-p '(4 1))
==> NIL
```

**NB**. Numbers are a poor substitute for booleans.

**PS**. I wonder if this is related to [How to check if all numbers in a list are steadily increasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54620566/850781)...

Comment: That looks fine. The 'or' & 'and' construct is what I thought of initially but which I couldn't do.

Comment: That's because you are trying to return numbers instead of booleans.

Comment: Yes. At first I 've done it using booleans (i.e. nil & t) but the Lisp compiler threw errors like "nil is not an integer" and the CLISP compiler in particular exited whenever I tried to run it. So I tried in vain doing it with the numbers :)

Comment: That's because you tried to conflate the step with the return value.