# How to check if all numbers in a list are steadily increasing?

Tags: list, numbers, common-lisp

I have several lists of varying length containing simple, positive integers, like `(2 4 1 3)` and I want to check whether or not all numbers are following each other after the list is sorted. This means the order itself doesn't matter but there are no gaps allowed.

`(2 4 1 3)` is correct

`(2 4 1 5)` isn't correct

Before I start to re-invent the wheel, I would like to know if there is an alternative to sorting the list and then checking whether or not the difference of the first and the second (and so on...) element is `1`.

**EDIT**

My example was not showing the complete task. The list does not have to start with `1` each time, i.e., `(6 8 7 9)` could also be a valid input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Optimal Solution

You need to check whether the set defined by the list is identical to `[a:b]`.
This is easily done by creating a [bit vector](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_bt_vec.htm) of the appropriate length.
This is **linear** (`O(n)`) in list length (requires scanning it once for [`length`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_length.htm) and `min`, and once for filling the bit vector), and requires some extra temporary memory for the vector:

```
(defun range-p (list)
  "Check that the list is identical to a..b as a set."
  (multiple-value-bind (min len)
      (loop for obj in list for len upfrom 0
        unless (integerp obj) do (return-from range-p nil)
        minimize obj into min
        finally (return (values min len)))
    (loop
      ;; 0: not seen this index in list yet
      ;; 1: already seen this index in list
      with indicator = (make-array len :element-type 'bit :initial-element 0)
      for obj in list for pos = (- obj min) do
        (unless (< pos len)
          ;; obj out of range
          (return-from range-p nil))
        (if (zerop (aref indicator pos))
            ;; obj is being seen for the 1st time; record that
            (setf (aref indicator pos) 1)
            ;; duplicate obj
            (return-from range-p nil)))
    ;; all list elements are unique and in the right range;
    ;; injectivity + same cardinality for finite sets => surjectivity
    t))
```

Tests:

```
(range-p '(2 4 1 3))
==> T
(range-p '(2 4 1 5))
==> NIL
(range-p '(-1 5 3 4 2 1 0))
==> T
(range-p '(-1 5 3 4 3 1 0))
==> NIL
(range-p '(2 4 1 a 5))
==> NIL
```

## Sorting

Sorting is linearithmic (`O(n*log(n))`) and thus clearly suboptimal.

## PS

This might be related to [Check consecutive numbers recursively using Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53820920/850781).

Comment: Very inspiring, but in my case the set has not to start with `1`, see my edit. I could see a possibility to use your solution after finding the smallest element and subtract it from every `obj`. But this would add addtional overhead.

Comment: @MartinBuchmann, since the sds’s solution requires in any case to scan the list once before performing the test, in this scan you can find the minimum value of the list as well and then use that value modifying appropriately the sds solution. This would solve the problem again with a `O(n)` algorithm, which is always optimal and much better than using a `O(n*log(n))` algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Putting together SDS's answer and Renzo's comment, I end up with this which works for me:

```
(defun min-obj (list)
   (loop with min = most-positive-fixnum ; sufficient in my case
         for obj in list
         when (< obj min)
           do (setf min obj)
         finally (return min))) 

(defun range-n-p (list)
   "Check that the list is identical to min..max as a set."
   (let* ((len (length list))
          (min (min-obj list))
          ;; 0: not seen this index in list yet
          ;; 1: already seen this index in list
          (indicator (make-array len :element-type 'bit :initial-element 0)))
          (loop for obj in list for pos upfrom 0 do
               (unless (< (- obj min) len) ; I deal only with integers
                  ;; obj out of range
                  (return-from range-n-p nil))
               (if (zerop (aref indicator (- obj min)))
                  ;; obj is being seen for the 1st time; record that
                  (setf (aref indicator (- obj min)) 1)
                  ;; duplicate obj
                  (return-from range-n-p nil)))
          ;; all list elements are unique and in the right range;
          ;; injectivity + same cardinality for finite sets => surjectivity
          t))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem mathematically using some of natural numbers like scan list in `o(n)` to find min,max,length and total sum then calculate sum of natural number using this formula

```
 actualMax = min+(length(list)-1)
    nSum = ((actualMax -min+1)/2)*(actualMax +min)
    nSum-total==0?"yes":"no"
```

let us consider

```
Ex -1 (6,8,7,9) min = 6 actual max = 6+(4-1) = 9,max=9, total = 30 naturalSum = 30 it is true
Ex-2 (6,8,7,10) min = 6 actual max = 6+(4-1) = 9,max=10, total = 31 naturalSum = 30 it is false
```

Comment: This method is not correct. Applied to (1 3 3 4 4 6) returns yes, which is wrong.

Comment: @Renzo In the question repeated number in a list is not mention so this solution works for discrete value in list.

Comment: Nothing is said about repeated numbers in a way or in the other, so I think the function should check for this possibility.

Comment: In my case numbers are not repeated. Sorry for not making the example clear enough.